# Dynamic search php ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am doing a simple search from a database with ajax using php. This is front end newSearch.php

```
            <<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getNodes(value){$.post("getNodes.php",{partialNode:value},function(data){
                $("#results").html(data);
            });
            }
        </script>
</head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <input type="text" onkeyup="getNodes(this.value)" placeholder="Search for nodes" />
            <br /> 
            <div id="results"></div>
        </div>

    </body>
```

and getNodes.php

```
$partialNode = $_POST['partialNode'];

 $nodes = mysqli_query("SELECT Node_Name FROM Nodes WHERE Node_Name LIKE '%$partialNode%'");

while($nodesArray = mysqli_fetch_array($nodes)){

    echo "<div>".$nodesArray['Node_Name']."</div>";

}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

But for some reason I don't get the result from database. I don't think it is because the front end, it might be because the back end. I only have one instance, node1. So I put "n" in the search box but nothing is displayed. I think it is a simple problem but can't see it.

Thanks

Comment: you have a dot instead of comma separating arguments of `$.post`. Use a syntax linter! There are numerous ones online even if you don't have one built into an IDE

Comment: Yes. Silly me. Thanks charlietfl

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here, you have dot instead of comma as argument limiter.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function getNodes(value)
        {
            $.post("getNodes.php",{partialNode:value}**.**function(data){
               $("#results").html(data);
            });
        }
     </script>
```

So, there you only need to replace "." with ",". :-)